# Azure SSIS Integration Runtime

Tags: oracle, azure, ssis

I am trying to deploy an SSIS project to an Azure SQL database.

I get the following error :

### TITLE: SQL Server Integration Services

The target server version of your project (SQL Server 2022) is unsupported on Azure-SSIS IR that currently supports SQL Server 2017. Please switch the target server version of your project to SQL Server 2017 using the latest SSDT.

For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2136401

---

Why can't Azure-SSIS IR support sql server 2022 ???

If I change the target server to 2017 my Microsoft oracle connection does not load data and throw an error....

Please help, appreciate it.

google as much as I can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this about a year ago.

I have not seen the reason documented, but have a  strong feeling that the Azure SSIS offerings are really just a stop gap to provide a pathway to get companies migrated to Azure platform.

My guess is that SSIS is not far off end-of-life and that DF tasks and pipelines will be the tech constituents that will replace SSIS packages.

SSDT not being updated post 2017 (standalone or bundled with SQL Server) is maybe one of the indicators / steps in this process.

BTW, if you have not have not actually deployed to Azure and tried to run your packages on the platform, then you might not have bumped into the issue we did using Oracle. The drivers we required were not provisioned (like SQL Server drivers were) on the servers Azure deploys in the cluster to host you IR. You need to go through a custom install process to get the drivers installed when the IR Starts. While are a number of steps involved, it is well documented. For us, it added unexpected complexity.

[Supported data providers for Oracle in Azure Data Factory SSIS IR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61210270/supported-data-providers-for-oracle-in-azure-data-factory-ssis-ir)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-configure-azure-ssis-ir-custom-setup

Once configured, the start time was around 35mins. A real pain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; it was very helpful. 
However; I tried to followed all the documentation on how to upload all the files with the custom setup script (main.cmd) to the blob container. I still get this error from Azure SSIS IR : Message":"Failed to execute custom setup script (main.cmd)."}], I wanted to as you : did you guys take the custom script (main.cmd) from the ORACLE ENTERPRISE folder in the preview container ? did you edit anything in the script or just move it to your blob container ?

Comment: Second question : In the Azure documentation, for the ORACLE ENTERPRISE folder, it says you need to  download the Microsoft Connectors v5.0 for Oracle (AttunitySSISOraAdaptersSetup.msi and AttunitySSISOraAdaptersSetup64.msi) from Microsoft Download Center and the latest Oracle Instant Client (for example, instantclient-basic-windows.x64-21.3.0.0.0.zip). Do you have to install all these files (including the instant client) in your local pc and then upload them or just upload them ? thanks